# php imgcropauto not cropping image

Tags: php, image, crop

I'm having trouble with php function imgcropauto.

I am trying to write a web app that will allow documents to be uploaded from various sites to a central server.

My aim is to autocrop the sides of the document out so that the image received from the users mobile device is similar quality to a scan. (similar to apps like office lens etc).

My php is below, but all it seems to be doing is rotating the image 90 degrees counter-clockwise and slightly dulls the colour.

(I have pulled out come unnecessary bits of the code and just included what is important).

```
if(!empty($_FILES['uploaded_file'])){
    $stamp = date("Ymdhis");
    $path = "../uploads/";
    $file = $_FILES["uploaded_file"];
    $temp = explode(".", $file["name"]);
    $newfilename = $stamp . '.' . end($temp);

    if(move_uploaded_file($file["tmp_name"], $path . $newfilename)) {
    }else{
        echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
    }
    $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($path . $newfilename);
    $cropped = imagecropauto($img, IMG_CROP_SIDES);
    if ($cropped !== false) {
        imagejpeg($cropped, $path . $newfilename);
    }
}
    else {echo "<h1>no file to upload</h1>";
}
```

Comment: You are trying to crop a pdf file?

Comment: Is your question about cropping, or rotating, or generating PDFs?  The code shown does all that, though by your comments it sounds like the rotation is unintended?  Please edit your question, try to focus on one problem you're having, and try to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Sorry, I copy pasted everything - have removed the unnecessary code now.

Once the image is cropped my next step will be to make it a pdf (to work with the system the images are going into), but that is not necessary for this question, so I took that code out.

Here I just want to crop the jpg.

Comment: OK, and what happens?  Is it not generating the files, or it is but they are not cropped as you expect?  Have you experimented with [the other cropping modes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecropauto.php)?  I'm not familiar with `imagecropauto` but it sounds like there is some potential for unexpected results, the algorithm has to evaluate what to crop ... have you tried different images?